# I installed timeline-vue but using it got errors

Tags: vuejs2

In my Laravel 5/vuejs 2.6 I  import https://github.com/pablosirera/timeline-vuejs

```
$ npm install --save timeline-vuejs
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ timeline-vuejs@1.0.5
updated 1 package and audited 17198 packages in 5.763s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

But when I insert code from this page I see error in console :

```
This dependency was not found:

* timeline-vuejs in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--4-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./resources/js/components/BS4/Test.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

To install it, you can run: npm install --save timeline-vuejs
           Asset      Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
/css/BS4/app.css   269 KiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
      /js/app.js  5.84 MiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app

ERROR in ./resources/js/components/BS4/Test.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--4-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./resources/js/components/BS4/Test.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'timeline-vuejs' in '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Hostels2/resources/js/components/BS4'
 @ ./resources/js/components/BS4/Test.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--4-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./resources/js/components/BS4/Test.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&) 23:0-38 53:14-22
 @ ./resources/js/components/BS4/Test.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./resources/js/components/BS4/Test.vue
 @ ./resources/js/routes.js
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/BS4/app.scss
```

My vue file which I filled from sample page:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row p-5 row_content" style="border: 2px dotted green; ">

            <Timeline
                    :timeline-items="timelineItems"
                    :message-when-no-items="messageWhenNoItems">
            </Timeline>

        </div>

        is_page_loaded::{{ is_page_loaded}}<br>

    </div>
</template>


<script>
    import {bus} from '../../app';
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import Timeline from 'timeline-vuejs'

    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                message: '',
                show: false,
                is_page_loaded: false,


                messageWhenNoItems: 'There are not items',
                dataTimeline: [
                    {
                        from: new Date(2018, 7),
                        title: 'Name',
                        description:
                            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius earum architecto dolor, vitae magnam voluptate accusantium assumenda numquam error mollitia, officia facere consequuntur reprehenderit cum voluptates, ea tempore beatae unde.'
                    },
                    {
                        from: new Date(2016, 1),
                        title: 'Name',
                        description:
                            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius earum architecto dolor, vitae magnam voluptate accusantium assumenda numquam error mollitia, officia facere consequuntur reprehenderit cum voluptates, ea tempore beatae unde.'
                    },
                    {
                        from: new Date(2016, 6),
                        title: 'Name',
                        description:
                            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius earum architecto dolor, vitae magnam voluptate accusantium assumenda numquam error mollitia, officia facere consequuntur reprehenderit cum voluptates, ea tempore beatae unde.'
                    },
                    {
                        from: new Date(2012, 1),
                        title: 'Name',
                        description:
                            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius earum architecto dolor, vitae magnam voluptate accusantium assumenda numquam error mollitia, officia facere consequuntur reprehenderit cum voluptates, ea tempore beatae unde.'
                    }
                ]

            }

        },

        name: 'test',
        // mixins: [appMixin],

        components: {
            Timeline
        },


        computed: {

        },

        mounted() {
            console.log('Test Component mounted.')

        },

        methods: {


        },

    }

</script>
```

That is strange, as in package.json I have :

```
"devDependencies": {
    ... 
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
},
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "timeline-vuejs": "^1.0.5",
    ...
```

Why error and how to fix it and why some strange error, as if the package was not installed at all?